# fetch data from Firebase into react-native application

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to fetch the data from Firebase into a React-Native application.

My current schema is somewhat like this:

```
-- arrayOfValues
    --- 1
        --- field1
        --- field2
    --- 2
        --- field1
        --- field2
```

Currently I am trying to fetch the full model under the UUID, but I am not able to do so.

The firebase config file which I am using is:

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XYZ",
    authDomain: "XYZ.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XYZ.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XYZ",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "12312",
    appId: "XYZ"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = app.database();
```

And I am importing this file inside a component like this:

```
import { db } from '../../../firebaseConfig';

const itemsRef = db.ref('movies/');
class CardInformation extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
        console.log("ItemsRef "+itemsRef);
        itemsRef.on('value', ( snapshot ) => {
            snapshot.forEach(snapshotChild =>  {
                snapshotChild.forEach(data => {
                    console.log("HiThere "+data);
                });
            });
        });

render() {
-----
------
}
export default CardInformation;
}
```

I am getting the ItemsRef to be printed as :
https://checkonce-34c7a.firebaseio.com/movies
inside which I have a schema like above and json like below:

```
{
    "arrayOfValues" : [
        {
            "field1" : "abc",
            "field2" : "3",
        },
        {
            "field1" : "xyz",
            "field2" : "3",
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I am not able to parse and print the arrayOfValues in the console.log 
Is there some issue with the code to parse the schema inside the componenDidMount function?

Comment: is this `console.log("ItemsRef "+itemsRef);` getting printed?

Comment: Nope... But what's there in the render function is getting displayed on the mobile screen.

Comment: Why you don't use react-native-firebase? And are you insure your app connects with firebase?

Comment: @DevAS --> Is there a formal guide to integrate with react-native-firebase?
How can I ensure that my app connects with firebase?

Comment: what do you mean of formal guide? check here https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/ - and you can open your firebase console and go to your Apps and check it

Comment: @DevAS, I have edited the question above, I am able to print the ItemsRef now, how can I print the array elements inside it. FYI, I am using the EXPO tool to debug and run the application.

Comment: What output of `console.log("ItemsRef "+itemsRef)`?

Comment: @DevAS: I printed that up there: https://checkonce-34c7a.firebaseio.com/movies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202487/discussion-between-devas-and-mshikher).